# OpenGL: Changing from Fixed Functions to Programmable Pipeline

Tags: delphi, opengl, matrix, glsl, deprecated

I'm trying to adapt some code from using the legacy fixed function pipeline to the modern programable pipeline and am struggling a little.

I currently have code that looks like this:

```
procedure TGLCamera.SetModelViewMatrix;
begin
  //calculate new look at point
  lookAt.x := self.eye.x - forwardVect.x;
  lookAt.y := self.eye.y - forwardVect.y;
  lookAt.z := self.eye.z - forwardVect.z;
  //set modelview matrix mode as current OpenGL matrix mode
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity; //load identity as a modelview matrix
  //set view parameters using OpenGL command
  gluLookAt(self.eye.x, self.eye.y, self.eye.z,
            lookAt.x, lookAt.y, lookAt.z,
            upVect.x, upVect.y, upVect.z);
end;
```

Would I still be using glMatrixMode, glLoadIdentity & gluLookAt ?

Do any of you know of some examples of before and after version 120?

Comment: Did you try Googling "Matrix Mathematics" ??? That would give you all the math behind those functions!

Comment: I have no idea why people keep downvoting without providing a comment on the *why*. The question doesn't show much research effort, that's kinda obvious, but one can at least tell the OP so they know next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern *core* OpenGL with deprecated functionality *removed* (i.e. core 3.1 or higher), the matrix stack, matrix manipulation functions and functionality layered on-top of said features (like GLU) is no longer available. For more info on legacy OpenGL, see [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL).

Therefore, the functions you mention will not be available to you when using either OpenGL 3.1 with a forward-compatible context or an implementation that does not expose `GL_ARB_compatibility` (as is the case, for instance, with Intel Sandy Bridge and higher CPUs on Linux) or, beginning with OpenGL 3.2, when using a *core profile* context. In the latter case, you can stick with the old stuff (although for new code I would strongly advise against it) by using a *compatibility profile* context. For more information on profiles and the rationale behind them, have a look at [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Profile).

The modern way to use matrices is to simply use whatever linear algebra library you have at hand and simply pass results from your calculations to a shader. A good library is groovounet's [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html). It also provides rewrites of old GLU functions, such as `glmProjection` or `glmLookAt` and handles all operations using column-major matrices, i.e. the format OpenGL expects.

For instance, the following shader contains a uniform 4x4 matrix representing the model-view-projection matrix:

```
#version 440 // ... or whatever modern version you're targeting
uniform mat4 ModelViewProjection;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position; // the attribute storage class is also gone in
                                          modern GLSL, layouts are very handy, e.g. to 
                                          avoid application-side location queries

void main()
{
  gl_Position = ModelViewProjection * vec4(Position, 1.0);
}
```

On the API level (i.e. in your application), you will need to pass the vertex attributes to you shader in the assorted ways modern OpenGL offers, the most obvious being to use a *vertex buffer object* as data store and (mandatory since OpenGL 3.2) a *vertex array object* describing *how* to pull attributes from said data store. And of course, you need to compute all the necessary data, like the MVP matrix, and pass them to a shader using either a *uniform buffer object* or the classic `glUniform*()` family of functions.

I general, for a good load of information on modern OpenGL, check the official [wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/) and assorted tutorials on the web, like [this](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) one I tend to recommend ('cause I know it's good).

Comment: Cheers,I've found online have been for C++ and recommend using GLM to do all the maths for you but unfortunately The application is in Delphi. I've googled around the maths but find it too detached from programming. I've managed to create the ModelViewMatrix & ProjectionMatrix stored in arries of 16x GLFloats. I have to create the NormalMatrix. I've extracted the top left 3x3 of the ModelViewMatrix but now need to "affine invert" it and "transpose" it ... (according to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941632/calculating-the-normal-matrix-in-opengl) ).

Comment: The page on Lighthouse3d goes into quite a bit of detail: [link](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/the-normal-matrix/)

Comment: @thokra: I think you mean core 3.2... there is no such thing as core 3.1. What you said is true, but the term "core" really was not a part of the lexicon of context creation yet; there was the "3.1 specification" (forward-compatible context) and then the "3.1 specification with `GL_ARB_compatibility` extension" (full context). 3.2 is when they did away with all this nonsense and officially distinguished between core and compatibility profile contexts in a sensible way. In 3.1 you should assume that all deprecated features are removed unless `GL_ARB_compatibility` is in your extensions string.

Comment: @thokra: I was referring to your usage of the term *"core profile" context* at the beginning of paragraph 2. This is undefined in GL 3.1, the closest thing that existed to a "core profile" in 3.1 was forward-compatible.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Edited! Excuse the unnecessary, albeit informative and correct rant. ;)